# WP Query works outside a function, not inside a function

Tags: wp-query, genesis-theme-framework

**Solution**: what worked in the end was adding

```
  global $post;
```

at the top of the query, so before

```
$custom_taxterms = ...
```

[Bill Erickson's Genesis custom loop](https://gist.github.com/billerickson/3218052) is the template I followed in the end.

**Original question**

I was hoping for some help with an issue that has me stumped.

I have the following query. It works and outputs data.

```
$custom_taxterms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'region', array('fields' => 'ids') );
// arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'stay',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 25, // you may edit this number
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'region',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $custom_taxterms
        )
    ),
    'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
);
$related_items = new WP_Query( $args );
// loop over query
if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If I now put it into a function, it stops working.

```
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'related_posts_cpt' );
function related_posts_cpt (){
    // same loop as above
}
```

Just to be clear, if I use the same function with a different output, it does work:

```
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'related_posts_cpt' );
function related_posts_cpt() { 
    ?>
    <p>AAAAAAAAHHHHHH</p>
    <?php
}
```

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since Genesis Framework is 3rd Party ( Not WordPress Core ) it is considered to be Off-Topic. That being said, a quick search came up with this [`Replace default Genesis loop with Custom loop`](http://www.genesissnippets.com/2012/09/15/genesis-custom-loop/) which may be of some use.

Comment: `wp_get_object_terms()` can also return `WP_Error`, so we might need to check for that too. Most likely your `$post` variable is undefined when you move your code inside a function, in a shelter from the global scope.

Comment: Have you tried using global $post;? also try to echo out your post id and other variables to make sure they are not empty.

Comment: Global $post turned out to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked! You should update your question with the working code so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

functions return an output.  you don't want to just echo it out.

try this as your function:

```
function mycoolquery() {
    $custom_taxterms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'region', array('fields' => 'ids') );
// arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'stay',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 25, // you may edit this number
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'region',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $custom_taxterms
            )
         ),
        'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
    );
    $related_items = new WP_Query( $args );
// loop over query
    if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
       $output =  '<ul>';
       while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();

            $output .= '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';

        endwhile;
        $output .= '</ul>';
    endif;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}
```

then echo out the function where you want it:

```
echo mycoolquery();
```

Comment: Indentation would be helpful here. Also note that `the_*` functions here can't be appended to string as they echo the output, not return it. The `$post` is also undefined, maybe you can use the post id as an input argument to the `my_cool_query( $post_id )` instead?